# Manually Windowing an IIR Filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, infinite-impulse-response

I am currently trying to window an analog IIR filter in order to obtain an FIR filter. Though I realize the fir1 function exists within Matlab, I was wondering to see if it could be done step-by-step to produce a notch filter at 0 Hz to eliminate any DC gains in the system. However, I quickly realized that I may not know what I'm doing :)

Firstly, I created a butterworth filter containing the characteristics that I'm looking for just for a comparison. Once the Chebyshev II analog filter was created, the magnitude and phase response was viewed. It doesn't show a bandstop at 0 Hz, but my guess is because it hasn't yet been windowed to show this result? I also wasn't too sure how to combine the window and analog filter, and would love it if someone pointed me in the right direction :(

```
Fs = 250;
n = 5; 
Rs = 40; 
Wn = [0.1*2/Fs, 0.2*2/Fs];
[b0,a0] = butter(3,Wn,'stop');
[b1,a1] = cheby2(n,Rs,Wn,'stop','s');
freqz(b0, a0, 4096, Fs);
w = triang(250);  
y = filter(b1,a1,w);
```

Comment: Would you like to see a very easy way to create a DC IIR notch filter, or is this approach you are taking educational for you?

Comment: Does it consist of using iirnotch()? :)

Comment: Dan Boschen has a great solution for digital second order IIR notch filters. But in the mean time I want to remind you that you don't **have** to window your IIR filter ('s impulse response) for any reasons other than implementing the filter via a time domain convolution which necessiates the availbility of a finite length impulse response. And your analogy between analog filters, digital IIR filters and windowing seems not proper (to me).

Comment: @Fat32 Hmmmm. I guess my logic for it goes as follows: An FIR filter can be created using an IIR Filter and a windowing function for purposes, as you have said, to filter via time-domain convolution. Based off that, I wanted to create an analog filter (which gives us an IIR), and then window that result to obtain the FIR filter.

Comment: Yes that's true and it seems I misunderstood your description of windowing. As you said you can create an FIR approximation (by truncation of an IIR impulse response) of an IIR digital filter, whose design is based on an analog filter prototype (such as a Butterworth or Chebyshev filter) by some suitable method such as bilinear transform. Then you need to compute the (truncated) impulse response first...

Comment: @Fat32 YOU'RE ABSOLUTELY RIGHT. HOW DID I FORGET??? The process should go: Analog prototype->Bilinear Transformation/Impulse Invariance ->Digital Filter -> Apply window. Should the impulse response be found/checked before the window is applied?

Comment: Yes.. before the windowing, you must have the truncated impulse response samples be generated already.

Comment: @Fat32 Perfect, thank you for your help Fat32! Everything has become much clearer for me moving forward :)

Comment: @Fat32 my solution doesn't answer his question but your response does-- you should paste it as the answer!  I think I already posted the notch filter solution elsewhere anyway unless that was the passband version...but this would be the first order equivalent so even simpler.

Comment: Ok @DanBoschen this time I'll make an answer from the comments... (In fact I do put comments when I don't want to post an answer, but anyway, let this be an exception!)

Comment: @Fat32 Look how happy and excited you made him? It's a great answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the classical world of digital filters, an infinite impulse response (IIR) filter is used for its computational efficiency while achieving supreme performance compared to a finite impulse response (FIR) filter.

Usually, implementing an IIR filter happens in the time domain, with an architecture of direct form-I, II or else which provides a solution of the linear constant coefficient difference equation (LCCDE) describing the filter.

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N} a[k]y[n-k] = \sum_{k=0}^{M} b[k]x[n-k]
$$

which is typically called an $N^{th}$ order LCCDE.

However, when there happens a need for implementing the IIR filter using time domain convolution instead;

$$
y[n] = h[n] \star x[n]
$$

then this requires the practical availability of the impulse response $h[n]$ of the IIR filter which is infinite length by definition.

To obtain a finite length, FIR, approximation $h[n]$ to the IIR digital filter, first choose your analog prototype filter, then apply the necessary transforms to get the digital IIR equivalent filter coefficients $a[k]$ and $b[k]$, and compute the truncated impulse response $h[n]$ of this filter, from $a[k]$ and $b[k]$ to a length that's adequate for the purpose of application and finally apply a further windowing to $h[n]$ if that's necessary...

The following MATLAB/OCTAVE command will give you a length $N$ truncated impulse response from IIR coefficients $a[k]$ and $b[k]$ with zero initial conditions.

```
h = filter(b,a,[1 zeros(1,N-1)]);
```

Comment: Ah, an even better well-formulated answer that helps me even further! Thanks again for all of your help, my mind was jumbled for a bit and you got me back on the right path and then some :)

Answer (score 3):

a DC-blocking filter is a high-pass filter.  i wouldn't use the term *"notch filter at 0 Hz"* for it.  usually, notch filters are for frequencies greater than zero and that means there are two notches at frequencies that are negatives of each other.

usually the DC-blocking high-pass filter is a discrete-time differentiator (has a zero at $z=1$) followed by a leaky integrator.   a leaky integrator is a LPF.  so you can window off *just* the LPF response to get an FIR and then pass that FIR impulse response through the differentiator (since that is FIR or length 2) and get another FIR that is one sample longer.

Comment: Potato, poetaughto :) Technicalities aside, it seems you were able to decrypt my intentions fine ;)

I completely agree with your solution! But I wanted to tackle filters from this angle so that I could get a better understanding of the process of design and how/why the steps are related :)

Though, I have a further question for you - if a filter needed to be implemented to eliminate a 60 Hz signal from the power-lines. Would you recommend a certain way over others regarding the design for this?

Comment: notch IIR filters are the most common way to eliminate a single frequency component.  and IIR high-pass filters are the most common way to eliminate DC.