# Lowpass Hann filter in Python

Tags: python, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response

I'm trying to design a FIR lowpass filter using Hann windowing in Python but I don't know where to start from... I have fc1,fc2, ft, rp and rs as parameters. This is my Python code:

```
            import myDSP
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import scipy.signal as signal
        import numpy as np

        def plotInTime(x,fs):
t=np.arange(0,np.size(x,0)/fs,1/fs)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,x)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.grid(True)

def plotInFrequency(x,fs):
N=int(np.size(x,0)/2)
if np.size(x,0)==1:
X=np.fft.fft(x,axis=1)
else:
X=np.fft.fft(x,axis=0)
X=np.abs(X)
X=X[:N]
f=np.arange(0,fs/2,fs/2/N)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(f,X)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.grid(True)
        fs, x = myDSP.readWav('Ring05c.wav') #is 22050
        myDSP.plotInTime(x,fs)
        plt.title('Original Signal')
        myDSP.plotInFrequency(x,fs)
        plt.title('Spectrum for the Original Signal')

        fc1=1200
        fc2=3000
        fc= np.arange(fc1,fc2+1)
        ft=150
        rp=0.1
        rs=40
        t = np.linspace(-1, 1, 201)
        #x = (np.sin(2*np.pi*0.75*t*(1-t) + 2.1)+0.1*np.sin(2*np.pi*1.25*t + 1) +0.18*np.cos(2*np.pi*3.85*t))
        wp=(fc-ft/2)/(fs/2)
        wp = wp[0]
        ws=(fc+ft/2)/(fs/2)
        ws = ws[0]
        L, Wn = signal.cheb1ord(wp,ws, rp, rs);
        b, a = signal.cheby1(L, rp, Wn,'low')
        f,H=signal.freqz(b,a,worN=256,plot=None,fs=fs)    

        y=signal.lfilter(b,a,x,axis=0)
        myDSP.plotInTime(y,fs)
        plt.title('Filtered Cheby1 Signal')

        myDSP.plotInFrequency(y,fs)
        plt.title('Spectrum for the Filtered Cheby1 Signal')
        y=y.astype('int16')

        w_fir = signal.firwin(65, fc/(fs/2), window='hann')
    [w,h] = signal.freqz(w_fir)
    plt.plot(w, 20*np.log10(abs(h)))
    plt.plot(w, np.angle(h))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to generate transfer function for Chebyshev Type I IIR filter and then convert to FIR by Hann windowing. The steps involved in converting IIR to FIR might be a little difficult but this post will help - [Manually Windowing an IIR Filter in Matlab](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38863/manually-windowing-an-iir-filter-in-matlab)

Generating Chebyshev Type 1 IIR Filter:
First determine order of filter using cheb1ord(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cheb1ord.html#scipy.signal.cheb1ord) and then generate the transfer function of filter using scipy.signal.cheby1 (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cheby1.html). To achieve 0.1 ripple below unity gain, you need to specify attenuation as 1 (so that $10^{-1/20} \approx 0.9$)

```
L, Wn = signal.cheb1ord(fc1/(fs/2), fc2/(fs/2), 1, 40);
b, a = signal.cheby1(L, 1, Wn,'low')
```

Now, from $a$ and $b$, you can get the IIR Impulse response $h$ by convolving with unit impulse response $\delta[n]$ for $N$ samples to get $N$ length filter. You can use scipy.signal.lfilter python command (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)  for this

```
x = np.zeros(65)
x[0] = 1    
h = signal.lfilter(b, a, x)
myDSP.plotInFrequency(h,fs)
```

where $x$ will be unit impulse impulse response $\delta[n]$ of length $N$ (1 followed by N-1 zeros).

Then generate Hann window of size $N$, refer (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.hann.html?highlight=hann#scipy.signal.windows.hann)

```
w=signal.hann(N)
```

$w[n]$, and do point by point multiplication over $h$. That is $h[n]w[n]$ for $0 \le n\le N-1$.

**UPDATE**: After doing the same above in MATLAB, I have found the optimum $N=65$ so that the Hann windowed FIR filter meets the pass band ripple and stop band attenuation. Bet ween $\omega=0$ and $\omega \approx 0.05\pi$(fc1), the passband ripple within 1dB. At $\omega=0.136\pi$(fc2), the stop band attenuation is more than 40dB meeting the filter specs with FIR Hann Window.

[image]

UPDATE: Code to add FIR LPF with Hann window using (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html)

```
w_fir = signal.firwin(65, fc1/(fs/2), window='hann')
myDSP.plotInFrequency(w_fir,fs)
```

Comment: I don't get a correct plot for the signal...

Comment: Please update your code in the questions so that I can see whats wrong.

Comment: Updated the code now

Comment: The 'x' in my code is different from your 'x'. My 'x' variable is an 1-D array of '1' followed by 64 zeros. So rename your original signal 'x' as 'x1'. Then, you need to multiply 'w' and 'x' point by point (both should be 65 samples long if everything is correct). Let the output be x_hann. The finally you have to do signal.lfilter(x_hann,1,x1) . I will try to edit your code.

Comment: first I need to implement using FIR Hann window and then implement an IIR filter using Cheby type 1 in order to compare the results..

Comment: I'll upvote you if you can help me

Comment: @jithin can you still please help me???

Comment: Your questions is not clear, you want to implement only FIR Hann filter or both FIR and IIR Filter? I see you have asked another question so that is why need clarity.

Comment: @jithin I've succesfully implemented the IIR filter but now I need to implement the FIR Hann filter and i don't know how to do this, I've edited my code in order to see what I've done.

Comment: ok, got it. I will update the answer.

Comment: @jithin why we only use fc1 and not fc2 also?

Comment: For low pass, we can specify only one cut off in FIR. See the documentation. But we can specify width also. Width = fc2-fc1.

Comment: @jithin i've also edited to see the photos in the code..

Comment: @jithin the purpose of this is to compare FIR filter with IIR filter, that's why I'm doing this, to see from plots which one it's better

Comment: You need to plot freqz of 'b,a' of cheby1 with that of 'w_fir'. I see that you are trying to plot  using plotInFrequency command, but your 'y' is wrongly generated. So don't do it. Just compare freqz of 'b,a' of cheby1 with 'w_fir'

Comment: so basically i need to plotInFrequency(f,fs) and then plotInFrequency(w_fir,fs)?

Comment: I am not familiar with plotInFrequency command. freqz will be a better choice. You already have written freqz for Cheby1 filter. Just write another for w_fir. Something like freqz(w_fir,1,fs).

Comment: @jithin you have the code for plotInFrequency and time, I've edited the question now.

Comment: @jithin I just want to use this functions because they are useful

Comment: can you help me please implementing this and finishing it?

Comment: @jithin I'll be more than happy if you can do this...

Comment: myDSP.plotInFrequency(w_fir,fs) looks fine. But for 'y' it may not work. Because 'y=signal.lfilter(b,a,x,axis=0)' , the 'x' here is not correct. The 'x' should be an impulse response. That is a single '1' followed by 64 zeros.

Comment: @jithin so basically the plot it's not correct

Comment: plot for w_fir will be correct. But the plot of cheby1 will not be. You need to give correct signal for 'x'.

Comment: @jithin so you say this are ok? w_fir = signal.firwin(65, fc/(fs/2), window='hann')
[w,h] = signal.freqz(w_fir)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(w, 20*np.log10(abs(h)))
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(w, np.angle(h))

Comment: @jithin I personally think that the plots for cheby1 are ok, don't you think this?

Comment: @jithin if you don't think it's ok why don't you make a separate post where you post the correct code for this comparison of signals?

Comment: @jithin it will be much easier for me to compare where I did wrong and what can I improve...and I can also vote your answer as the correct one

Comment: I have edited my answer to show generation of 'x'. Also added plotInfrequency lines for both the filters. Try it.

Comment: @jithin it's working, thanks, but why the plot for cheby1 and hann it's different? on hann i have frequency vs magnitude, on cheby I have time and amplitude...

Comment: @jithin here you can see the difference between them: https://imgur.com/a/rYtyxGy

Comment: @jithin i'm just trying to compare the two of them, if u can t help me with this..you say that it's wrong implemented but you don't say why...X it's bidemensional array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106912/discussion-between-robinson-constantin-chera-and-jithin).

Comment: @Robinson-ConstantinChera Thanks. The system is complaining about the level of comments on this. **Please use the chat!**

Comment: @PeterK. sorry, are my plots correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation when using new functions: [scipy.signal.firwin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html)

1. You either provide `pass_zero` option or two cutoff frequencies. So in your case you don't have to use this option.
2. The first argument corresponds to the length of the filter. So it has to be an odd integer.
3. You either provide the sampling frequency or express the cutoff frequencies as relative frequencies (in your case something like `fc1/fs`).

In summary, for a a filter of order `n`, you can get your coefficients as

`signal.firwin(n + 1, [fc1, fc2], fs=fs, window='hann')`

Comment: not exactly what I asked for, but thanks...

Comment: I've edited my code, can you check it please?